# Cant change the value of the NullValue property in a DataColumn

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dataadapter, datacolumn

When i try to change the NullValue property to (Empty), or (Nothing) i get the below error. how do i get around this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Null is not applicable for int/double/DateTime types but for types e.g. string, byte[] etc it will work fine.